# Sticky Footer Solution with variable height

Tags: html, css, layout, footer

I've been working on finding different ways to handle a sticky footer.  There are many different solutions, from using fixed height and margins to using javascript or flexbox, etc....  I wanted to find one without using frameworks that worked with responsive templates and no fixed height which seems to be much tougher.

Comment: It is fine to use jQuery for your solution?

Comment: in theory it should be, since the display is inline-block it should stack correctly.  I don't see any reason it wouldn't

Comment: [This link](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/) should help you using flex

Comment: Where did i say i wanted to use flex?  I specifically said i dont want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I came up with is the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="siteWrapper">
   <header>header content</header>
   <div id="siteContent">site content</div>
</div>
<footer>footer content</footer>
```

CSS:

```
html{ 
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}

#siteWrapper{
   min-height: 90vh;
   width: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
}

header{
   100%;
}

footer{
   width: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
   clear:both;
   min-height: 10vh;
}
```

I made the footer min-height and site wrapper min-height total up to 100vh.  I also made the footer vh large enough to fit at least a row of text, though it seems like this can be adjusted for effect, etc...  The footer has to be outside of the "site wrapper" as well.

I don't know what the particular quirks to this solution might be, but it seems to be fairly straight forward and working well.